# Struggling with command-line Android app development

Tags: android, command-line

I've been working my way through developing a simple "Hello World" application for Android on the command-line.

Ideally, I'd like to use a tool like CMake, or Meson so that I can manage a larger application in the future.  It seems those tools are severely lacking support for Android, even though Android has now been a thing for 15 years.

It seems the Android developers have decided that the only way to build apps is via  Android Studio, but, I personally hate working within IDEs.

I have tried to follow the instructions for using Gradle, which seems to be a possible alternative for Android Studio, but, those instructions are quite simply, HORRIBLE.  Gradle itself looks like a complete mess of a tool with a over-complicated usage paradigm.

Considering that an Android APK is really nothing more than a slightly reorganized Java jar file, how is it possible that this has all been made so incredibly messy to work with ?

ANy help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to be in control and understand what is happening.  It seems the people in charge would prefer I am just another idiot script -kiddie

Comment: Even if you don't want to use AS/IntelliJ, would recommend using it for the very least...  
1. Project creation - takes seconds and gives you a reasonable standard Gradle configuration with modules.
2. Checking dependency updates - it's tedious if you try and manage this manually, especially as a project grows.
The accepted answer is very basic without modules, modules will significantly improve incremental build times if used correctly. Once you have a project template you can dev in any editor and run Gradle builds from CLI without issue, no need for AS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building an android application using Gradle is truly simple without need to use Android Studio.

First of all you need to download android SDK. Also you need to know about AGP which is a plugin for Gradle. this plugin adds some tasks such as 'assemble' task which create an APK for you.

Here is some steps to build an android application in command-line:

1. Make an empty directory called "scratch" and then `cd scratch`.
2. run `gradle init` in this directory then select basic project type and kotlin DSL for build script.
3. open the `settings.gradle.kts` and set repositories for plugins (it tells Gradle that where looking for the plugins which we add later) and also set repositories for dependencies (these dependencies are libraries that you add later). So add these lines of code to top of the project name in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

4. Now to make sure that you are in the correct way just run `./gradlew` in your root directory ("scratch" in this example).
5. open `build.gradle.kts` and add plugins to your project and then config your android project.

```kotlin
plugins {

    id ("com.android.application") version "8.2.0"
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20"

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.scratch"
    compileSdk = 34
}
```

the first pluglin is AGP which is used for creating an android application and the second plugin add kotlin to your project. (as we used AGP 8.2 in the code above so make sure that your Gradle version which is written in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` be 8.2)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
```

6. You should create an src folder to put your source code and resources such as images there, So run `mkdir -p src/main/java/com/example/scratch`.
7. the final step is creating a `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `src/main` directory. So write this inside your AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</manifest>
```

8. Use `./gradlew assemble` to create your APK (it will be created in `build/outputs/apk` directory).

Now you can add activity and start developing your application.

Note that Android studio creates a module for your application but we didn't create any module so if you want to create module you can change some of above step a little bit to do it. (it is simple)

Comment: Wow !  Seriously, thanks for the first concise, helpful set of instructions I have found in the last 3+ days of searching.  I'll have a few more questions shortly.

Comment: @Smit-Tay You're welcome, if you have more questions feel free to ask.